# Masked symmetry sculpting?

Tags: vertices, sculpting, mirror, masking

[image: Demonstration]

What I'd like to do is make it so I can symmetrize sculpting the edges, but only the edges and nothing else. Furthermore I'd like to set it so affecting the north also does the south, the east does the west, and vice versa.

Furthermore, I'd like to make it so affecting one of the corners affects the three, that way I can ensure the normal I'm trying to create is even across the board and doesn't suffer any discrepancies. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kIFG1S7sArU

Turns out this is exactly what I wanted!